# iOS: MapKit: How can i set the number of annotations that search request fetches

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have the following code for retrieving restaurants inside my application

```
NSLog(@"getting restaurants");
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurant";
request.region = self.mapView.region;

MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];

    [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        MapViewAnnotation *annotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithPlacemark:item.placemark];

        annotation.title = item.name;
        annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.location.coordinate;
        //annotation.subtitle = item.placemark.addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
        //annotation.phone = item.phoneNumber;

        [annotations addObject:annotation];
    }];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
}];
```

How can i set the limit for how many annotations to be loaded ? 
Now, only a handfull of the available points are loaded. When i zoom in further, i call the code again, and additional points appear.

Comment: you may set a counter while adding objects to annotations array. if goes larger than your specified number. just stop adding to array.

Comment: i am getting to few..not to many :)